# Border around specific table row

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, border

I am trying to create a border around the top row ONLY!  Currently, a border will be displayed only around the outside of the table.  But I also want a border around the first row.  Can someone help me do this?  I want the row with 'Team, Correct Picks, and Points' to have a border around it.

```
<body>
    <?=$leaguename?>
    <center><table cellspacing="0" style="width:400px; border:1px solid gray">
    <?
    echo "<tr border=\"1\"><td> Team </td><td>Correct Picks</td><td>Points</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($memberslist)) {
        if ($row['User_ID'] == $id) {
            echo "<tr style=\"border:1px solid gray\" bgcolor=\"gray\"><td>" . $row['User_ID'] . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['User_ID'] . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    ?>
    </table></center>

</body>
```

Comment: You really need to [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/). You cannot have a `<h2>` as a child of `<table>`.  Apply a border to the `style` attribute of the first `<tr>`, or better, put it in your CSS file.

Comment: I tried adding border=1, but that did not work can you post what you are suggesting??

Comment: Invalid and non-semantic HTML interspersed with heavy PHP logic. If you carry on with code like this, you are going to be in development hell very quickly. Check out an MVC framework like Symfony, Yii or CodeIgniter, and start looking at using CSS-based layouts if at all possible.

Comment: None of this is invalid because it is working.  Yes it is not a desirable way, but I currently don't care.  Please help me with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is presentational, so mixing it into the PHP is a bad idea. Instead, use CSS:

```
tr:first-child td { border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
tr:first-child td:first-child { border-left:1px solid black; }
tr:first-child td:last-child { border-right:1px solid black; }
```

IE7+8 support for the *-child selectors can be a bit buggy. If it's not working in those browsers, consider using JavaScript polyfills.

You may also want to put the headers inside `<thead>` and `<th>` elements to make the `<tr>` with data the first row in a `<tbody>` element.

e.g.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```